# Block for serial output in GNURadio/GRC

Tags: serial-port, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am working on a project that involves GNU Radio/GRC and am not very familiar with the software. I am trying to output data to a serial port in GNU Radio using a block, but have not found a way to do so.

I was wondering if there is a pre-defined block that I can use to put this information to a serial port (USB on a Raspberry Pi 3), or if I had to create my own block.  And if I had to create my own block, what that code would look like.

I have been able to write the data to a file using the File Sink to make sure I was getting data, and was wondering if the fix is something as simple as changing the File sink to an serial port sink.  See picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcyRY.jpg
[image: fg excerpt]

I also did some research and found a github repo that looks like what I need -- unfortunately, the repository that it links to is no longer there.  It did mention using pyserial, which is what I believe is meant for creating my own block in python.  The link to this repo is below:

https://github.com/jmalsbury/gr-pyserial

Comment: hint: operating systems have a screenshot function, which makes far better and easier pictures than using a camera to photograph your screen... also, GRC even has an export button for PNGs. Throttling in your example makes no sense. Giving your files a .grc ending is bad practice, as that is the ending reserved for GNU Radio flow graphs. Giving it a .txt ending is plain misleading, since there's no text involved whatsoever. Please read http://tutorials.gnuradio.org !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> … was wondering if the fix is something as simple as changing the File sink to an serial port sink.

Yes! Or No, it's even easier:

So, in fact, you could even simply use your file sink to write to e.g. `/dev/ttyS0` (or `/dev/ttyUSB0`, or whatever is the device name of your serial port), but you'd have to set up the serial port to work like you want it to separately first. A way of doing that would be using `stty`, e.g.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 115200
```

prior to running your flow graph.

Note that practically all in your flow graph point points to you not being sufficiently proficient with GNU Radio to successfully exchange data. I can't cover everything here, please read the [official Guided Tutorials](http://tutorials.gnuradio.org), but:

- In a flow graph like yours, where the IO is the inherently rate-limiting element, you *must* not use "Throttle". Throttle is really just a tool to avoid a flowgraph consuming all your CPU (and to slow down simulations)
- Giving your files a .grc ending is bad practice, as that is the ending reserved for GNU Radio flow graphs.
- Giving it a .txt ending is plain misleading, since there's no text involved whatsoever. The "file format" (I wouldn't even call it a format) is really just plain binary numbers, as your computer handles them; not decimal ASCII representations of these floating point binary numbers

> I also did some research and found a github repo that looks like what I need -- unfortunately, the repository that it links to is no longer there. It did mention using pyserial, which is what I believe is meant for creating my own block in python. The link to this repo is below:

Don't know what you're referring to, https://github.com/jmalsbury/gr-pyserial is perfectly existing!